# Number of combinations of n terms

Tags: python, algorithm, math, combinations, discrete-mathematics

Is there an algebraic formula to tell me the different combinations of `n` temrs?

If I have:

```
{0: ['Hello!']}

{1: ['Welcome']}

{2: ['to']}
```

All the combinations would be:

```
['Hello!',  'Welcome', 'to'],
['Hello!',  'to',      'Welcome'],
['Welcome', 'Hello!',  'to'],
['Welcome', 'to',      'Hello!'],
['to',      'Hello!',  'Welcome'],
['to',      'Welcome', 'Hello!'],
```

But what is the formula that describes this? Then I would use the formula to write my program and create all the possible triplets from the words I have available. I have looked at this link but havent figured out the anser:

https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html

Comment: Could you give an example where not all of the lists are one element?

Comment: Should be 3x2x1. For the first slot you have 3 choices, then 2 for the 2nd, then only 1 for the third.

Comment: But I think your 5th and 6th rows should start with `to`, if I'm following you correctly?

Comment: Yes sorry, I am fixing it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the **permutations** of `n` terms, `itertools` has a permutations method. You can use it as follows:

```py
import itertools

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
z = itertools.permutations(lst, len(lst))

print(list(z))
```

If you want to learn more: https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

```py
import itertools

def permutations(iterable, r=None):
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    r = n if r is None else r
    for indices in itertools.product(range(n), repeat=r):
        if len(set(indices)) == r:
            yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

lst = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
z = permutations(lst, len(last))

print(list(z))
```

Answer (score 4):

What you're describing is the *number of permutations of n objects*. There are *n! = 1 × 2 × ... × n* (also known as *n factorial*) such permutations.